# is it possbile to add comma in this SQL?

Tags: linux, shell, sed, grep

I have a statement like this

```
UPDATE `test`.`scores`
 SET
   id=1
   name='kobe'
   score=99
 WHERE
   id=1
   name='kobe'
   score=100
 UPDATE `test`.`scores`
 SET
   id=2
   name='tmac'
   score=70
 WHERE
   id=2
   name='tmac'
   score=100
 UPDATE `test`.`scores`
 SET
   id=3
   name='rose'
   score=80
 WHERE
   id=3
   name='rose'
   score=100
......
```

how to add `,`, `and` & `;` in it ? I want my result like

```
UPDATE `test`.`scores`
 SET
   id=1,
   name='kobe',
   score=99
 WHERE
   id=1 and
   name='kobe' and
   score=100;
```

Comment: I have edited your post assuming what you want, if it's not the one that you want then edit your post please.

Comment: Where did that first bit come from?  It might be better in the big picture to fix *it* to do the right punctuation.  It should have the needed context.  Otherwise you need very weird scripts (see the various answers) to reconstruct that context in ad hoc ways, all of which are fragile and could break in the future if the file changes.

Answer (score 3):

There must be something simpler than this:

```
awk '
/^ *UPDATE/   { prevsep=";" }
/^ *(SET|WHERE)/{ prevsep="" }
{ if(previous)print previous prevsep; previous = $0; prevsep = sep }
/^ *(UPDATE|SET|WHERE)/{ prevsep="" }
/^ *SET/  { sep="," }
/^ *WHERE/{ sep=" and" }
END { print previous ";" }'
```

Each line is remembered in `previous` and printed with a previous separator set
from a separator `sep` triggered after that line by the keywords UPDATE SET WHERE. These keywords also clear the previous separator (or set it to `;`) so the previous line is printed without comma or `and`.

Comment: +1. awesome, but weird ;)

Comment: @Rahul I agree it is weird. I arrived at it step by step but I'm having a hard time trying to simplify it so it is more obvious. I'd hate to maintain these sort of scripts!